# Does an algebra over a $\mathbb{F}_2$ of countable dimension have a grading where each component is finite?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, exterior-algebra, graded-rings

I have a commutative unital $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra $Q$ of countably infinite dimension, and I want to see if it has a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading where $Q_i=0$ for $i<0$ and $Q_0=\mathbb{F}_2$ and $Q_i$ is finite for $i>0$. I also impose the condition $q^2\in\{0,1\}$ for all $q\in Q$.

I know that the exterior algebra $E$ on countably infinitely many generators $\{x_i\}_{i\geq 0}$ is a commutative unital $\mathbb{F}_2$-algebra and has such a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading (also $x^2\in\{0,1\}$ for all $x\in E$), see Proposition 1.5 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.0137.pdf). This made me wonder if it is possible in a more general setting.

It is clear that we can choose a countably infinite basis for $Q$, but not clear how this can be used to form a grading. How might I go about this?

Comment: Take a quotient of the exterior algebra on generators $x_n$ for $n \geq 1$ by the relations $x_n = x_{2n} x_{2n+1}$. If you assume that each $x_n$ is homogeneous, then you can see there is no way to put a grading on this algebra that satisfies the conditions you want: $x_1 = x_2 x_3 = x_4 x_5 x_6 x_7 = \cdots$. Is it clear that each $x_n$ must be homogeneous? Can you make this into a counterexample without that assumption?

Answer (score 4):

If such a grading existed, then in particular there is a surjection $Q\to Q_0$, the quotient by the ideal $Q_{>0}:=\bigoplus_{i>0}Q_i$. A $\mathbb F_2$-algebra need not admit such a surjection to a finite-dimensional $\mathbb F_2$-algebra.

For example, if $Q=\overline{\mathbb F_2}$ is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb F_2$, then $Q$ is a field, so the only surjection it has is to itself: $Q=Q$.

Comment: Thank you for this. I notice that the above condition of a surjection $Q\to Q_0$ is satisfied with the additional requirement that $q^2\in\{0,1\}$ for all $q$. Do you think there is a good prospect of a grading under these stricter conditions?